# Is there a translation for Micro services in French ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Bonjour, je suis en train d'écrire sur [micro services](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) pour une personne française et je voudrais savoir s'il y a une autre manière de le dire et si oui, quelle est la plus connue.

C'est clair que je ne suis pas français.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro- et services existant déjà en français, il n'est pas utile de chercher à les traduire.

« Architecture microservices » est couramment employé.